# Add an email recipient to an email sent from Salesforce

Tags: apex, email

Is it possible to dynamically add an email recipient to an email sent from Salesforce?
What I wanted to achieve is: 
If an email is sent to the email address a@google.com it should additionally be sent to the email address b@google.com. 

On the other way around, if an email is sent to b@google.com, it should be sent to a@google.com too.

I don't want to do this from a specific quick action, lightning component or visualforce page. I want to do this every time an email will be sent from Salesforce. Regardless of the function that is sending the email.
I already tried to put additional email addresses into the EmailMessage.ToAddress field with a before insert trigger but this does not seem to work.

Any ideas if I can get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate your emails from APEX, you can do this while generating the email.  However, what you are asking for, I do not believe is possible.  There is no "catch-all" for outbound emails from SFDC.  (Note: the before-insert trigger on the email object would fire after the email has already been sent, but before committing to the system.)

Here is a related question/answer:
[Is it possible to modify outgoing emails via Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82346/is-it-possible-to-modify-outgoing-emails-via-apex)